# Why does Grails merge nested g:include tag params into a single list

Tags: grails

if i have a outer include

```
<g:include controller="video" action="list" params="[page:1,size:6]"/>
```

which does include in its view another controller

```
<g:include controller="actor" action="list" params="[page:1,size:3]"/>
```

the params for ActorController are merged if they have same names.
So in above example the

```
params.size == [3, 6]
```

But i would expect it to be just *3*. If i move the exact include from actor to top level it does behave like expected.

What is this behaviour? Can it be turned off? Can we walk around it? Is it a bug?

EDIT: i was using recent Grails version 3.2.4

EDIT2: i did now create a grails 3.2.4 project which reproduces this.

```
git clone https://github.com/aistomin/includes-bug.git
```

open localhost:8080 and check console for messages.

EDIT3: workaround from @vahid does work wonderful

```
params.list('page')[0]
// instead of
params.page
```

it works even for case when the value is not a list and doesnt fail when the value isnt given at all

Comment: must be happening simultaneously if you post to list params="[size:1,size:2]" you will receive it as described you can instead do params.list('size') and if you have this then iterate through otherwise just treat it as single field

Comment: Which grails version are you using? I've tested it with grails-3.1.10 and can't reproduce it.

Comment: @gregorr sorry for not writing this in the original question (i did edit and add now), we use Grails 3.2.4.

Comment: @gregorr i also added a test project to github if you would like to check it again. its in description, EDIT2 section

Comment: i did file now a Grails issue for either fixing or documenting this behaviour. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10424

Comment: Are you sure that order is guaranteed, for the workaround?  Also, it's possible that the presence (or absence) of a param could be meaningful.  This really feels like a grails bug to me; hopefully the grails developers will comment on this one soon!